# ArrayList.indexOf kills the code, but doesn't crash the program, nor is it catched

Tags: java, arraylist

I've got this code

```
public String[][] checkBoxes(String[][] varden){

    ArrayList[][] tillatnaSiffror = new ArrayList[9][9];

    for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
        for(int ruta=0;ruta<9;ruta++){

            if(tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta] == null){
                tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta] = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                for(int add=1;add<=9;add++){
                    tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta].add(add);
                }
            }
            if(varden[i][ruta].equals("X")){
                for(int a=0;a<9;a++){
                    try {

                        System.out.println(tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta].indexOf(Integer.parseInt(varden[i][ruta])));
                        System.out.print("Testing");

                    } catch(Throwable n){
                        System.out.print("Throws exception");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta]` is an ArrayList containing the numbers 1-9, and the variables `i` and `ruta` are from for loops that wrap around my code. The two-dimensional array `varden` contains strings with digits 1 to 9. The problem is, instead of printing the index I'm looking for, it does nothing. And it doesn't print "Testing" afterwards either, and it's not catched because of an exception either. I counted the amount of exceptions.

However, if I put in zero's like this:

```
System.out.println(tillatnaSiffror[0][0].indexOf(Integer.parseInt(varden[0][0])));
```

Then it prints out the index, and also the "Testing" text. Any ideas why it doesn't work with the variables? It's not an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` problem; the variables are correct.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code in a debugger?

Comment: Something in your diagnostics is screwed up, basically. But it's hard to say what without any way of reproducing the problem. If you run it in a debugger and break into it, what happens? Have you tried adding a finally block in case something's swallowing an exception?

Comment: Without seeing *actual* source code, there's lot a not of help we can give.

Comment: I've added more code now, I hope it makes it clearer. And Oli, I ran it through eclipse's debugger, but it didn't report anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without the whole code and without knowing what exception is thrown, my only suggestion is to split that line into multiple statements and see where it pops. Then you'll probably be able to find the answer yourself.

```
String s = varden[i][ruta];
int i = Integer.parseInt(s);
List<Integer> l = tillatnaSiffror[i][ruta];
int idx = l.indexOf(i);
System.out.println(idx);
```

**Edit:**

```
if(varden[i][ruta].equals("X")){
```

and then inside that `if`:

```
Integer.parseInt(varden[i][ruta]))
```

Do you see the problem?
BTW, you don't seem to use `a` of the third `for` anywhere, is that right?

Comment: Yes, I definitely see the problem now! The part that got parsed was supposed to have that `a` variable instead of `ruta`, hence the for loop. Thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 1):

Almost certainly, you're getting a runtime exception, which is unchecked - meaning the compiler doesn't warn you needs catching. The most likely runtime exceptions you are getting are `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` or `NumberFormatExcpetion`.

To "fix" this, try `catch (Throwable e)` instead - that will definitely catch anything thrown inside the `try`. I suspect you are not *actually* catching Exception but some subclass thereof.

Comment: Why catch `Throwable`? Do you think he gets an `Error`?

Comment: I agree with Marius ... and an Error is (or really *should be*) program-fatal. No indication the code raises another Throwable either. I suspect the problem is in with the example given in the post.

Answer (score 0):

The code will either:

- print 'Testing'
- throw an `Exception` which is caught by the 'catch' block
- or throw a `Throwable` that is not a subclass of `Exception` and that is caught elsewhere.

Not all `Throwable`s are subclasses of `Exception`: `Error`s are subclasses of `Throwable` but not `Exception`.

Comment: -1 All Exceptions **ARE** subclasses of `Exception`, especially `RuntimeExceptipn`

Comment: [Basic Java Exception Hierarchy](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/exceptions/exceptions_hierarchy.shtml) -- note the difference between Exceptions and Errors. However, I concur with the other two bullets so, +1. I believe the code in the post is "lacking".

Comment: Updated the answer to be more accurate, indeed this is not a checked/unchecked thing but an exception/error thing.